# Navigating back to Parent activity with toolbar

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-toolbar

so to break it down.

I have two activites: A main activity and a subactivity.

When I am in the subactivity, I want to press the return home button
on the toolbar and return back home.

I tried putting android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY in manifest, but I still couldn't get it to work. Maybe I'm not seeing something obvious here. Hope you guys can help.

Here is my subactivity.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.final_create_cardview_1_image);

        //Toolbar
        myToolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_pic);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }

    private void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar myToolbar)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == android.R.id.home)
        {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Now here is my manifest. The first activity being the main activity. And the second activity being the subactivity.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="Promenade"
            android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".CardFinal.imageActivity">
            </meta-data>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


  </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CardFinal.imageActivity"
            android:label="PickImage">
        </activity>
```

I'm not quite confident if I'm doing the manifest correctly, the other solutions on stackoverflow are very confusing. If I can have a straight forward answer to this, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @DemoMail You mean a switch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == android.R.id.home)
    {
        //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
          finish();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

manifest is wrong

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="Promenade"
       > 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


 </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CardFinal.imageActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MyActivity"
        android:label="PickImage">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MyActivity">
        </meta-data>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use Intent or onBackPressed() method

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == android.R.id.home)
        {
            //intent your parent activity
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourActivit.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          finish();

         //Other way
         onBackPressed();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 }
```

Try this.

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do it currently is by overriding the onSupportNavigateUp() method, if you use AppCompatActivity.

Here's the code in Kotlin:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    onBackPressed()
    return true
}
```